# С# Увеличение числа в диапазоне

Tags: c#

Есть два текстовых поля для ввода семизначного числа, где 1 поле: стартовое число, 2 поле: конечное. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу получить список чисел в этом диапазоне?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант использовать `Enumerable.Range();`

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
foreach (var i in range)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Выход:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @SyntaxWEB6stPRODWowSuite На здоровье! Рад, что смог помочь.

Comment: Тогда уж проще и короче написать обычный `for`.

Comment: @Regent Где он проще и короче? Так вызвать один метод, который = 1 строке, а с циклами строки 3 минимум.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `for (var  i = 0; i < 10; i++)` - первая строка, `Console.WriteLine(i);` - вторая.